# C# - Are C#'s naming conventions in Unity3D's API just completely different than Java's?

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine, naming-conventions

Java user here. Recently I was playing around with the Unity3D editor, and while I was trying out C# scripts, I realized that the way fields, methods, and etc. are named are very different than what I am used to doing in Java. I am not in any way saying I know everything about Java's naming conventions, but just saying from experience. For example:

In Java, I usually name methods (non-static) in all lower-case. However, in Unity3D, I see this for the initialization function:

```
void Start() {

}
```

or how I usually name enums in all upper-case, but there's this:

```
KeyCode.UpArrow
```

or static fields (in this case it's a static property, so I don't know since there isn't really a Java equivalent as far as I know )

```
Vector3.up
```

So all in all, I'm just confused. Am I mistaken about my observations about C#'s naming conventions as far as Unity3D is concerned? Is there a smaller difference between that and Java's than I think? Is Unity3D just naming things differently from everybody else?

Any clearing up in this matter is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The case of classes, enums, static variables etc.. is simply a preference, nothing should be implied or inferred by the lack of or existence of case or a naming convention.  It's simply a choice/preference and can be applied in either Java or C#.